# JQuery Click Child when Parent Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a long day....

I have this code below

```
<div class="background" onclick="javascript:$('this checkbox').click();">
    <div class="picture"> 
       <img class="colors" src="458x395.png" />
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="nothing" name="check" class="selsts" />
</div>
<div class="background" onclick="javascript:$('this checkbox').click();">
    <div class="picture"> 
       <img class="colors" src="asdfag3.png" />
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="aff4t" name="check" class="selsts" />
</div>
```

And its supposed to click the checkbox. I can't distinguish by name, class or id, I have to use the type. I also need to make sure its within the parent div and nothing else.

Any idea why this isn't working?  I'm sure i'm just having a stupid moment. :\

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="picture"> 
       <img class="colors" src="458x395.png" />
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="nothing" name="check" class="selsts" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('div.background').click(function() { 
  var checkBox = $(this).find('input:checkbox'); 
   checkBox.attr('checked', !checkBox.attr('checked'));
});
```

Comment: This will get stuck in an infinite loop since clicks on the checkbox will bubble to the `div`.

Comment: Fixed. It will toggle checked

Comment: +1 I like how you toggled the check box with the negation operator.

Comment: The only problem with this is that it doesn't update the UI instantly. At least not for me... I need to figure out whats up with it :|

Answer (score 1):

As you're using jQuery, you should probably not be using the `onclick` attribute to bind your event handler.

The main problem is that your passing a string to jQuery. That string is interpreted as a selector, and will look for an element of type `checkbox` that's a descendant of an element of type `this`. Obviously, that's not going to exist.

You want something more like this:

```
$("div.background").click(function() {
    $(this).find(":checkbox").click();
});
```

Or, you can pass `this` to jQuery as a context (which is equivalent to using `find`):

```
$("div.background").click(function() {
    $(":checkbox", this).click();
});
```

Note that I'm using `:checkbox` instead of just `checkbox` (with the `:`). That's a selector that matches `input` elements of type `checkbox`.

***However, there is likely to be a big problem with this. You're going to get stuck in an infinite loop (since DOM events bubble up the tree). You will need to capture the `click` event on the checkbox and stop the propagation of it there.***

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery is looking for a `this` tag, which doesn't exist. You shouldn't inline your JS. And `.click()` doesn't check the DOM when you add new elements, so try this:

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="picture"> 
        <img class="colors" src="458x395.png" />
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="nothing" name="check" class="selsts" />
</div>​
```

then to get it to actually check the checkbox use (this is jQuery 1.7):

```
$(".background").on("click",function(e) {
    var chk = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]')[0];
    chk.checked = !chk.checked;
});​
```

**this solution doesn't run into the DOM bubbling issue James describes**

Answer (score 0):

Your passing this in as a string, not as an object.  Jquery will not understand the scope of this.  Consider attaching the function outside of the html to separate concerns

Try this it will allow the user to check/uncheck and will not propagate the event creating a loop.

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="picture">
       <img class="colors" src="458x395.png" />
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="nothing" name="check" class="selsts" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".background").click(function(e){
        var chk = $($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']"));
        if(chk.attr('checked'))
        {
            chk.attr('checked',false);
        }else{
            chk.attr('checked',true);
        }

       });
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fycFB/

Comment: This works great, but there is a caveat I forgot to mention... I'm using tzCheckBox replacement to replace the box with a span - That seems to be screwing it up... How can I get around that?

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="$(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked','checked')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need like this ?

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){ alert('Checked');});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JF2xu/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="background" style="border:1px solid black;" onclick="javascript:$(this).find(':checkbox').attr('checked',true);"> 
                    <div class="picture"> 
                    <img class="colors" src="458x395.png" />
                    </div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="nothing" name="check" class="selsts" />
            </div>
```

Comment: What if he wants to uncheck it?

Comment: I probably was a sleepy, when answering this question. )