# simulate click when parent div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to trigger a click on an `<a>` tag when it's parent div is clicked

for this structure

```
<div id="menu_container">

                <ul id="header_links_container">


                    <li class="header_link header_link_large border_box_1">
                        <a class="header_link" href="http://amazon.com">LINK 1</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="header_link border_box_1">
                        <a class="header_link" href="http://google.com">LINK 2</a>
                    </li>


                    <div class="tbc"></div>

                </ul>

            </div>
```

using this

```
$('#menu_container').on('click', 'li.header_link', function(){
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).children('a.header_link').click();  
});
```

produces and infinite amount of clicks. I guess because when I trigger the click() on the `<a>` tag, it's parent div also receives a click and so it just does everything again.

How can I simulate a click on my anchor when it's parent div is clicked? Trying to use the answer from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9537518/1252748) isn't working.

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/ucatir/1/edit)

Thank you

Comment: what are you trying to do, just log it? You can achieve the same thing other ways. Your question is very explicit (and impossible), so you might get better help if you tried "I am trying to do X and here's what I've tried"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Elements click method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.click) instead of jQuery's.

```
$('#menu_container').on('click', 'li.header_link', function(){
   console.log('clicked');
   $(this).find("a.header_link").get(0).click();
});
```

Also you shoul try it on your computer as [@Sushanth --](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941272/sushanth) suggests.

Comment: thank you. what does the `(0)` indicate in the jquery `get()` part?

Comment: `.get(index)` returns underlying HTML node element from the set of elements returned by the selector. The element returned by `.get(index)` is not a jQuery object anymore instead it is the raw HTML node which you can get with pure javascript's `getElementById` etc... So when you call the `click` event on this object you are not calling jQuery's `click` event instead you are calling elements click method. And `0` is the index. Since our selector returns (or should return) one and only one element we can confidently get the first value from it. http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: this solved the identical problem for me. Never occurred to me that jquery was the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot trigger a click** event for a Anchor such that you can go to that particular source..

You need to click it explicitly to get it work in the way you are expecting.

The best option you can try is to use `window.location`

Try this

```
$('#menu_container').on('click', 'li.header_link', function(e){
   console.log('clicked');
   var loc = $(this).find("a.header_link").attr('href');
   window.location = loc;
});
```

This will not work with `jsBin` as it tries to stop redirects.
Try on your local machine
​

Comment: I don't really understand why you've moved the click event to the `<a>` tag. It doesn't really do anything when you click the `<li>` Thank you though!

Comment: I think I misunderstood your Question.. Check Updated post